# Unable to get any routes to work in Laravel 4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4

I am struggling to get Laravel 4.2 to work on my Digital Ocean server running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5. I can get the screen that shows the Laravel logo where it says "You have arrived". I am tired and it is late, but I am getting very frustrated and I really have to get this working tonight.

**My routes are as follows:**

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::any('monkey', function()
{
    return View::make('monkey');
});

Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
?>
```

I cannot get it to say "hello" or "monkey". What gives???

I have already gone into the apache.conf and changed the "AllowOverride" to "All" from none and restarted the Apache service.

**My laravel.log file shows this:**
`production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException'`

**Update:**
I just tried adding the following route with no change...

```
<?php
Route::any('test', function()
{
    return 'Test This!!!';
});
?>
```

**Update 2:**

Here is my .htaccess file under public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: are you getting errors ? what is happening when you are trying to hit those routes ?

Comment: try `Route::get('/', function(){ echo 'hello'; });` does that work?

Comment: have you tried `Route::any('monkey', function(){return 'monkey';});` ?

Comment: In the logs I am seeing this in the log: production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException'

Comment: When I go to the base address of the URL it doesn't show "hello".

Comment: @pthurmond the base url is `app/public` if you are able to reach 'you have arrived' page then I'm sure you're able to reach all other routes, try to request `app/public/index.php/monkey` what is the output?

Comment: Ok, I am actually getting some useful information now. From the monkey version of that (http://107.170.21.171/index.php/monkey) I see a message about the view being not found. With my new test route (http://107.170.21.171/index.php/test) I am seeing the text. So now the question is why do I have to put in index.php?

Comment: Does that mean my .htaccess is messed up?

Comment: yes you have to set .htaccess file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable mod_rewrite as it generally isn't enabled by default.

Run the following commands in terminal to enable it.

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: That was it. I thought it was enabled. I guess I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: In server already mod_rewrite is enabled, changed .htaccess but still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `.htaccess` file inside `app/public/` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is exactly what the .htaccess file looks like.

Comment: Though I really appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: On the positive side, at least the alternate route loading is working. So I gave you an up vote for that part.